# Difference between HTML parser and validator

Tags: html, validation, parsing, syntax

I have been told there is a difference between an HTML parser and validator.

Can somebody explain the difference to me?

Answer (score -1):

This is a terminology question. It all depends on what sort of information you want in return.

Parse - read through a file and extract data that I can use later on (like for presenting it on the screen).

Validate - read through the file to see if the file is in a format that I can then parse.